# body css rule and google-caja

Tags: google-apps-script, google-caja

If i am not mistaken, google-caja removes body css rules. Since HtmlService sanitizes all html css and javascript using caja, we can't style the body element.

Is there any workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a workaround [here using jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1534#c4); hopefully it might be suitable for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully we will see this caja bug fixed soon.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known Caja bug (I don't have the bug ID handy but it should be on the Caja issue tracker) and will be fixed in a release or so I think. In the meantime, add a `<div>` around your entire page and style that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think you are referring to this issue 
[link](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1305&q=body). I will try your solution.

Comment: Since r5044 of google-caja this is fixed but gas currently uses r4969 if i am not mistaken. Any information as to when it's going to be updated?

Comment: It should be fixed within 2 weeks.